# Can't find the man page for Xdialog

Tags: 14.04

When I type man xdialog in the terminal, an error pops out saying: no manual entry for Xdialog.

Is it normal or am i missing some man pages for this command?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be normal, according to the [changelog](http://xdialog.free.fr/doc/changelog.html) Xdialog has been updated in 2006 the last time. It appears to be not maintained anymore and therefore has been dropped from repositories.